# Solve the differential equation for obtaining $x$ as a relation of $t$: $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\alpha\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, kinematics

**Question:** Solve the differential equation for obtaining $x$ as a relation of $t$:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\alpha\sqrt{x}$$

**My attempt:** $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\alpha\sqrt{x}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\alpha\sqrt{x}\cdot 2\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2\right]=\frac{4}{3}\alpha\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(x^\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{4}{3}\alpha x^\frac{3}{2}+c_1$$

Now we have $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}\alpha x^\frac{3}{2}+c_1}=\sqrt{k x^\frac{3}{2}+c_1}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{\sqrt{k x^\frac{3}{2}+c_1}}=dt$$

Can anyone suggest how to proceed? Any substitutions?

Comment: This is very close to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1553597/97236) that is about to be closed. Non-elementary functions appear. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: @mickep No. I am not familiar with such functions at all. This problem was from the chapter on central forces. Thought it would be easy but turned out to be very frustrating and difficult.What should be solution without using Mathematica? Any manual steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$x''(t)=\alpha\sqrt{x(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2x(t)}{\text{d}t^2}=\alpha\sqrt{x(t)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2x(t)}{\text{d}t^2}\cdot\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}=\alpha\sqrt{x(t)}\cdot\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\space\frac{\text{d}^2x(t)}{\text{d}t^2}\cdot\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\space\text{d}t=\int\space\alpha\sqrt{x(t)}\cdot\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\right)^2=\frac{2\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\right)^2=\frac{4\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+2\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+2\text{C}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}}{\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+2\text{C}}}=\pm 1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\space\frac{\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}}{\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+2\text{C}}}\space\text{d}t=\pm\int\space 1\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{_2\text{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-\frac{2\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3\text{C}}\right)\cdot x(t)\sqrt{\frac{2\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\text{C}}+3}}{\sqrt{6\text{C}+4\alpha x(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}=\pm t+\text{F}$$

With $\text{C}$ and $\text{F}$ is an arbitrary constants